# BOT Authentication Using the external client

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have enabled the Cortana channel in BOT framework. The BOT framework is used from the client application through the directline channel.
Following is my work scenario:
 - For couple of actions in BOT framework, i need to authenticate the user through the client application (internally it uses Owin.Oauth for External providers such as google, FB authentication)
 - Then retrieve the access token in the BOT framework from the client and then pass that to my authorized service for the further activity

- I need to achieve this in both **Cortana and client BOT directline** as well
- **Following are the different steps I followed:**

1)  CORTANA - Enabled the Connected Account service But its not my requirement since i always need to force the user to login to the client application before the activity. Also, Connected account is tied to the Cortana. In my scenario, the user should be logged in to the client in order to use the BOT feature

[Connected Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/configure-connected-account)

2) I checked the following code sample in BOT Auth and it does the authentication  inside BOT framework using the OAuth

[BOT framework OAuth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleGenericOAuth2Bot)
I dont want to handle the authentication in my BOT framework as well

All I need is a Auth token from the client which i can use to authorize my WEB API from the BOT framework for the same provider

I tried the following to get the auth token and the user Identity information from the client through BOT framework but not yet tested completely. I am not sure the cookie and other implications

**MY Client application Strtup Auth:**

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
             Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                 OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
         app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

         app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

         app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleclientid"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleclientsecret"],
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()

        });
```

Is there any API call that i can use from API to get the following details from the client because I dont know which email address that the user used while logging in to the client application

1) Provider

2) User Email address

3) Authtoken and validity

Comment: Can i set BOTState in my web client as soon as successfull authentication so that it can be accessed in my Bramework:                        var botCred = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);
            var stateClient = new StateClient(botCred);
            BotState botState = new BotState(stateClient);
            BotData botData = new BotData(eTag: "*");
            botData.SetProperty<string>("AccessToken", authResult.AccessToken);

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: not yet jason !!